# How to read from a secure websocket with Tink in C++

Tags: c++, websocket, openssl, boringssl, tink

I'm working on a C++ client app that needs to read from a secure websocket. After looking into some websocket libraries I would like to use [easywsclient](https://github.com/dhbaird/easywsclient) but it does not support TLS.  I tried adding support for URLs that start with wss using OpenSSL by following [this](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=22078&seqNum=3) article but would like to avoid loading certificates and private keys from files (if possible). I looked into how this is done in boost asio and they recommend using [certify](https://github.com/djarek/certify) to access a platform's TLS keystore. I also researched chrome browser and found that it uses BoringSSL which lead me to Tink. However, I can not find an example of how to use Tink/BoringSSL to secure a websocket and deal with client side certificates and keys. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You cannot implement TLS without "loading certificates and private keys". They are core fundamentals of TLS. It is an open question how straightforward or complicated this is accomplished with various TLS implementations, but in some form or fashion this must be done, otherwise TLS is worthless.

Comment: Yes, its more a question of how to make this work seamlessly so I don't have to setup cert and private key files on each box that is running the websocket client.  When you use chrome to visit a https site you're not asked to setup a key or cert first. Same with this python websocket lib https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html. You can read from a wss socket without any additional setup or key config.

Comment: Update... I was able to get [lws](https://libwebsockets.org/) working against a wss websocket with OpenSSL so will code some C++ wrappers around that.  I think my issues were more related to how I was adding OpenSSL support to [easywsclient](https://github.com/dhbaird/easywsclient).  Thanks to anyone that spent time on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Clients that want to read from a websocket do **not** have to setup cerificates and private keys, this is only relevant for a web socket server that must suport tls/ssl.
As I do not know much about C++ , I can only give you an example in PHP for a client connecting to a  websocket server using TLS/SSL. Here the client prepares a $context in order to use TLS/SSL vai a stream.

```
$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer_name', false);
```

Later on the connection is made using this context,

```
$this->socketMaster = stream_socket_client(
"$prot$Address$Port", $errno, $errstr, 30, 
STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context
);
```

For the full source go to:
https://github.com/napengam/phpWebSocketServer/blob/master/phpClient/websocketCore.php

Comment: Hi Heinz, thanks for your response.  I saw on some other stackoverflow threads that disabling verify can open you up to MITM attacks so am slightly hesitant to go with this solution.